# Reading and Processing twitter network data

Tags: bigdata, twitter

I have this big data collected from [here](http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/twitter). So what I would like to asks are

1. How to perform file I/O with the file? From the download like it was mentioned that it used .tsv format, but after unpacking I got .twitter file which is foreign for me and so far I haven't found any reliable documentation regarding file I/O of this file type.
2. Since the file is huge, supposed i could do file I/O it is still impossible to load everything to a single machine (It is 23 gigabytes in size). What is the tools that is perfect for this, say for graph processing? Is pyspark the right tools?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't downloaded the 5GB tar- TSVfile, but there is also a small file "Extraction code: download `twitter.tar.bz2` (14.46 KiB)"  on the konect.uni-koblenz.de website you mentioned.

This `twitter.tar.bz2` file is a small archive of several binary executables designed to run on Linux. The README says the following

> ## Usage
>
> To build the datasets, execute "make" or "stu" inside the directory.
>   The code downloads the datasets from their online sources and converts
>   them to the KONECT format.
>
> ## Dependencies
>
> You may need to install the following additional software packages:
>
> - unzip
> - aria2
> - tofrodos (providing fromdos/todos)

So I assume they want you to convert this to KONECT format (whatever that is) and use their MATLAB toolbox to process the dataset.

Alternatively, the third file linked `twitter.n3.bz2` on their website is an [RDF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) which I haven't looked at. It is in [N3 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation3). You can process the file with java-based Tomcat-Webapp [Blazegraph](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_Start#Load_Data) for instance, but you need to know a lot of stuff to setup this software, and it is complicated to use even for smaller datasets (say 100 kb).

Maybe other graph databases (besides Blazegraph) can read in .rdf Files, but I don't know any. But see [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30604/weighted-graph-database-with-rdf-support) on Softwarerecs.sE

Comment: I just found. The thing is if possible I don't want to redownload the dataset if possible (I have poor connection right now and I happen to be lucky enough to finish downloading the tsv file), do you think the provided code will help?

Comment: No I don't think it will help much. The files/binaries in `twitter.tar.bz2` are poorly documented (and not guaranteed to run), and the bittorrent file that it wants to download might be offline, or blocked by your corporate firewall.